# trac daily update on ticket

Tags: trac

I'm using trac for project management. I want to send my colleagues a daily summary email of the updates on tickets, so that they are aware of the progress. Is there any tool/script that does this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you are asking for, but on the [Trac notification](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracNotification) page you can find information about how to configure trac for sending updates when a ticket has changed.

You can also take a look at this [plugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/FlexibleReporterNotificationPlugin) it might help you out. ( I haven't actually used it myself).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing a custom report, it takes a bit of SQL knowledge but you will get exactly what you need. Go to view tickets and create a new report.

Example 1 - To get changes to a specific ticket since a given date:

```
SELECT date(tc.time, 'unixepoch'), tc.field, tc.oldvalue, tc.newvalue
FROM ticket_change tc
WHERE tc.ticket='$TICKET' AND
date(tc.time, 'unixepoch') >= '$DATE'
ORDER BY tc.time
```

TICKET and DATE are variables for the report. For instance if this report is number 45 and I want to see changes made to ticket 1017 since 1-jul-2011 I will call: http://trac/devel/report/45?TICKET=1017&DATE=2011-07-01

Join with ticket to track changes for a component, milestone or user...

Example 2 - To get changes to a specific milestone since a given date:

```
SELECT date(tc.time, 'unixepoch'),t.id, tc.field, tc.oldvalue, tc.newvalue
FROM ticket t
LEFT JOIN ticket_change tc ON t.id=tc.ticket
WHERE t.milestone like '$MILESTONE' AND
date(tc.time, 'unixepoch') >= '$DATE'
ORDER BY tc.time
```

Here MILESTONE and DATE are the parameters.